# Making a collection of child nodes in Lodash

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have a data structure where there are opportunities, and each opportunity has notes.    I want to take all of the notes of all opportunities related to a person and show them.  Right now I have the below, which works.  However, what I'm thinking is there has to be an easier way, where I could not have the external array, but instead return the same result as .value() from opportunityNotesList.

```
    const thisNotes = {}
    const opportunityNotesList = _(opportunities)
        .map((opportunity, id) => ({id, ...opportunity}))
        .filter(opportunity => opportunity.linkToContact === id)
        .map(opportunity => {
            _(opportunity.notes)
                .map((note, id) => ({id, ...note}))
                .each(note  => {
                    thisNotes[`${note.id}`] = note
                })
        })
```

Really just looking for a more elegant way to pull off this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `_.flatMap` to avoid nested loops

```
 const thisNotes = _(opportunities)
    .filter({linkToContact: id})
    .flatMap('notes')
    // way 1 - if id is really necessary
    .map((note, id) => ({id, ...note}))
    .keyBy('id')
    // way 2 - if id is unnecessary
    .reduce(function(result, note, id) {
        result[id] = note;
        return result;
    }, {});
```

Comment: You can replace the `.reduce()` with `.keyBy('id')` if you keep the `.map()`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest don't try to be too elegant. I'm already having a hard time tracking the above code, imagine another dev has to pick it up and make a change!

Seperate it out into it's own helper, or better a selector (using `reselect` for example).

I agree, these kind of transformations become quite painful over time - its one thing I seem to continue to hit my head against.